# I can only launch gvim from the terminal and not from the Unity launcher

Tags: launcher, gvim

I installed vim-gnome and it works great when I launch from the terminal with gvim command. However, whenever I type vim or gvim in the launcher it finds nothing.

When I launch from terminal it has "[No name] - GVIM" in the bar, so I'm guessing I just need to include a name somewhere, I just need to know where.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu .. 16.04? I just installed it on 16.04 and went to the start and typed g and it was the first item that showed. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim-gnome` It should put an item in the start. The No name issue is not the problem that is because you have a blank document open .. if you opened a document in GVIM it would have the documents name instead of No name

Comment: I'm on 14.04. You are right about the [No name], thanks. I have reinstalled it, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: I don't have a 14.04 version available to me at the moment ... not sure if its set up the same way or not but ... I believe the `.desktop` files are located at `/usr/share/app-install/desktop` .. do you have that folder and if so do you have a file in it called GVim?

Comment: The are there. I don't have a GVim one, but I do have vim-gui-common:gvim.desktop. I have tried vim in the launcher too, but that doesn't bring up any result either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

On your desktop create a blank document and call it `GVim.desktop`

Open the file and copy and paste in the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=vim-gnome
X-AppInstall-Popcon=1158
X-AppInstall-Section=main

Name=GVim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
TryExec=gvim
Exec=gvim -f %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=gvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data
```

Save the file. Right click the file and click Permissions and check the Allow executing file as program. Your desktop should now have a shortcut for vim-gnome that says GVim with the proper icon. If so then try to run it. If it launches the program properly then open terminal and do the following:

```
cd Desktop
sudo chown root:root GVim.desktop
sudo desktop-file-install GVim.desktop
```

It should now show in the start (Unity launcher).

Once you have done this and its showing in the launcher you can delete the file you created on your desktop

```
cd Desktop (if you arent already there)
sudo rm GVim.desktop
```

And you should be all set